# Is it possible to integrate testflight with azuredevops

Tags: ios, azure-devops, testflight, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I have azure devops build pipeline running to build iOS apps.

As of now I have CI/CD, right from building the apps to distributing the apps to testers through hockey kinda of mechanism

But I'm just wondering ,is it possible to push the build with test flight.

Does test flight offer API for this ?

Can I attach release notes as a part of test flight build ?

P.S

is it advisable to use test flight to have so much frequent releases ?

is it possible to submit the app for external testing automatically without manual intervention ?

every week we release 10 to 15 builds to testers. But our release to app store will be once in a month.

Comment: read about Fastlane, there are questions about building a pipeline on SO

Comment: Little confused about pushing build with testflight. Does the **push** means trigger? Let testflight trigger builds?

Comment: By push I mean sending the build to testflight

Answer (score 5):

Yes, absolutely you can build iOS apps on Azure DevOps and deploy the IPA to TestFlight.

See the Azure documentation for specifics - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops#deploy

Also, be sure to install the [Apple App Store Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store).  You'll then need to go into your project settings to make a service connection in order to use it in your yml.

In terms of, `is it advisable to use test flight to have so much frequent releases ?` - I'd argue yes, you want to make sure your delivery pipeline is intact so that you're always ready to go to production.  There's no harm in publishing to Test Flight and not use a given build.